# any WYSIWYG editor for RuleML?

Tags: wysiwyg

[RuleML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuleML) is a markup language developed to express both forward (bottom-up) and backward (top-down) rules in XML for deduction, rewriting, and further inferential-transformational tasks.

Is there a WYSIWYG RuleML editor? I want to write rules for my rule engine.

I searched few websites but could not find any. I have found S2Red but it is not WYSIWYG.

Any platform. The cheaper the better.